# Scaling and cropping an image adaptively based on the window dimensions

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, css, image

I've tried my best (I'm new to JS) to write a script that make an image fit to its parent div with respect of the ratio and overflowing when needed.

For example, if the `height` of the image is smaller than the window's `height`, I set the `height` equal to the window's `height` and the `width` overflow the window's `width`. I then horizontally center the image.

If the `width` is smaller than the window's `width`, I do the way around.

An example can be seen here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/rjpnr5zt/)

**Note that the example doesn't work as I'm seeing it on my browser (Chrome).** Refresh simulation might not work properly.

The fact is that everything is working as expected when I refresh the page. If I try to resize the page, the ratio is not respected at all. But then again, If I refresh the page (after it's been resized), the image fits perfectly.

```
function imageFitToScreen() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var postThumbnailWidth = $('#postThumbnail').width();
  var postThumbnailHeight = $('#postThumbnail').height();
  var imageWidth = $('#postThumbnail').find('img').width();
  var imageHeight = $('#postThumbnail').find('img').height();
  if ((windowHeight < windowWidth) && (imageHeight < imageWidth)) {
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('width', 'auto');
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('height', '100%');
  }
  var imageWidth = $('#postThumbnail').find('img').width(); /* imageWidth value has changed with the if before */
  if ((windowHeight < windowWidth) && (imageWidth < postThumbnailWidth)) {
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('min-width', '100%');
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('height', 'auto');
  }
  if ((windowWidth < windowHeight) && (imageWidth < imageHeight)) {
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('width', '100%');
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('height', 'auto');
  }
  var imageHeight = $('#postThumbnail').find('img').height(); /* imageHeight value has changed with the if before */
  if ((windowWidth < windowHeight) && (imageHeight < postThumbnailHeight)) {
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('width', 'auto%');
    $('#postThumbnail').find('img').css('min-height', '100%');
  }
}

$(window).on("load", imageFitToScreen);
$(window).on("resize", imageFitToScreen);
```

I double the `var imageHeight` and `var imageWidth` before they are called again because they change within the first and third `IF`.

I don't know if it's important for you to know that I'm changing the `#postThumbnail` width/height before I run this script.

```
function refreshDynamicSize() {
  $('#content').find('#postThumbnail').css('min-height', $(window).height() - $('header').height());
  $('#content').find('#postThumbnail').height($(window).height() - $('header').height());
  $('#content').find('#postThumbnailTitle').css('line-height', $(window).height() + 'px');
  $('#content').find('#extend').css('min-height', $('#postThumbnail').height());
}

$(window).on("load", refreshDynamicSize);
$(window).on("resize", refreshDynamicSize);
```

What I'm looking for is an optimisation of the code as it works on refresh but not on resize.

It might surely be really simple (like change in execution order, or an "on.load" something...).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I believe your question is off-topic; is this code that you have broken?

Comment: I guess not. Code was functionning but not perfectly. I wanted to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like the kind of thing that should be done purely in CSS using [media queries](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), specifically [`orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation).  When the window is taller than it is wide, the rules inside

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { … }
```

… would apply.  When the window is wider than it is tall, it would be

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Furthermore, I would consider that image to be [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) styling for `<h2>The post title</h2>` rather than an `<img>` element in its own right.  The scaling should be handled by a [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) rule.

Comment: Hi 200_success and thank you for your answer which is quite nice!

I tried to follow it using the following code : 

`@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
    #single\.php #postThumbnail img {
        width:auto;
        min-width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
}

@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
    #single\.php #postThumbnail img {
        width:auto;
        min-width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
}`

But unfortunatly if the image is larger than the window it won't resize (get smaller) to fit.

Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, if I understand right your statement, I cannot make the image a `background-image` as it is generated by Wordpress. I'm actually making a template. And I don't want to mess around.

Comment: But you have full control over the CSS, right? Does the image src need to vary from page to page?

Comment: I do, but I don't know how to manage how to put a generated URL inside a background-image: url();
I do think that the image src is page-dependent. Each article will have it's own thumbnail generated by wordpress.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with WordPress, but I suppose you could use a jQuery hack to extract the URL out of an `<img src="…">` and transfer it to `<h2 style="background-image: url(…)">`.

Comment: One last question, @200_success : the fact is that my h2 can be larger than the window's width. If I change it's line-height to 1em, it won't vertical align anymore. Any idea how to vertical align it even if it has a 1em line-height? (I was setting the line-height in javascript equal to the window's height)

Comment: Nevermind : I used a `display: table` on the parent and a `display: table-cell` on the child.

A bit of `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @200_success I finally figured out a way to deal with it.

This is way simplier than my actual javascript script.

CSS :

```
#single\.php #postThumbnail {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(240, 240, 240)0%,rgb(225, 225, 225) 100%);
}

    #single\.php #postThumbnail img {
        display: none;
    }

#single\.php #postThumbnail #postThumbnailTitle {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

 #single\.php #postThumbnail #postThumbnailTitle h2 {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: rgb(40, 40, 40) 0px 0px 2px;
            line-height: 1em;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top center;
        }
```

jQuery

```
function imageFitToScreen() {
    var url = $('#postThumbnail').find('img').attr('src');
    $('#postThumbnailTitle').find('h2').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
}
$(window).on("load", imageFitToScreen);
```